# Access system cursor image form JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, browser

I need to make a visual effect in that multiple cursors (pointers) are shown simultaneously in different parts of a webpage. The easy solution is to make my own *.cur image and to use it as a 'cursor' css property value for the *real* cursor and as an image with fixed position for all the *fake* cursors. By I'm not going the easy way!

I try to access the system's (or browser's) default cursor image and use it, so that everyone will see his own cursor, not mine custom one.

Is there any way to access this image? I mean the one that is used than the css 'cursor' property is set to 'default'.

Comment: quick answer: it's not possible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533287/css-custom-cursors

Answer (score 0):

I believe that to be an Operating System cursor, not browser. I would go for the easy solution to use an custom image for the cursor and using the same image for the fake cursors